# Appfabric caching and recycling of application pool

Tags: asp.net, caching, appfabric, application-pool

Where is the appfabric cache stored in memory?

We have a web site that uses appfabric cache.

Appfabric cache is set up with high availability, enterprise edition of windows 2008 and secondary cache.

If we recycle the application pool that the web site uses by editing the web.config on all servers will be loose the cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If you recycle the application pool, nothing happens to the appfabric cache.

Remember that you need to deal with this fact in your application.

Answer (score 1):

AppFabric Cache is a **distributed** cache -- the optional local cache component is in-process and would be lost on application pool recycle, but the core AppFabric Cache service itself is a remotely-hosted cache. If you use Powershell to restart the cache cluster, or if you stop/start the service through Windows Service Manager, the caches on the cluster will lose all state, like recycling an app pool.